# QGIS3.x using processing algorithms outside of python console (when writing a plugin)

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, select-by-location

For a school assignment I need to write a QGIS plugin.
Part of the plugin that i'm writing needs to use the 'select by location' processing tool on a previously created buffer.

The codelines that I want to use is:

```
import processing
```

```
def selectBagFromOverlapBuffer(self):
        self.layer1 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('bag:verblijfsobject')
        self.layer2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('buffer')
        processing.runalg('qgis:selectbylocation',self.layer1, self.layer2,u'within',0)
```

The error message I get is "module 'processing' has no attribute 'runalg'
Is there a step I'm missing with accesing processing tools from a plugin .py script?

Comment: Use "run"  instead of "runalg".

Comment: Thank you so much! that seemed to make it work, except for 1 more error that occurs:

" return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
              File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 130, in runAlgorithm
              if context.feedback() is None:
             AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'feedback'"

What do they mean with "feedback" ?